# starting tomcat on port 80 on CentOS release 5.5 (Final)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, centos, port

I want to start Tomcat 6.0.29 on port 80.
My OS is CentOS release 5.5 (Final)
I changed following line in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

to

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Then I run command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

In file $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.log I found such exceptions:

```
java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:80
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:565)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    ... 12 more
0:11:56 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start:
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: `java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:80
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1094)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
0:11:56 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you do this as root, and not only uses sudo?

Comment: From the stack trace it is clear this happens in native code, so the security manager shouldn't be involved. The only reason I manage to think of is a non-root user trying to bind a privileged port. Can you run with strace to see what, precisely, it actually chokes on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The ports in the range 1-1023 are privileged. Only root is allowed to bind to them.

There is at least two ways to solve this:

- Run as root. You need to weight the extra security risks this infers, of course; both security holes in Tomcat itself (which I believe to be few) and those your web applications contains (which can for example lead to letting people read /etc/shadow as an example), against this being simple and straight-forward.
- Run as service with jsvc. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/setup.html for details on jsvc. It is some extra hassle to setup, but root will only be involved in setting up the ports, Tomcat will then run as a user without special rights. I recommend this for any serious setup.

Regardless on what way you choose, the actual starting of Tomcat will need root privilegies.

///BR, JenEriC

Comment: Hm, I missed the sudo part of the start command. That should work. I'm at a loss to why it doesn't; sorry.

Comment: I always prefer starting tomcat on port 8080 and letting iptables to do the job of forwarding all requests from port 80.

Comment: @mindas: That would of course work, but it doesn't explain the problem at hand :-/

Comment: absolutely - this is why I only posted a comment to your post, and not answered the question myself. In general, I think your answer actually addresses the problem (hence the upvote).

Comment: You are right. In script /etc/init.d/tomcat6 runned /usr/sbin/tomcat6 with user - tomcat. When i runned: sudo /usr/sbin/tomcat6 start - everything works fine. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 10):

Run Apache in front of Tomcat and connect all requests on Port 80 (Apache) to Tomcat on the AJP port (8009) using mod_rewrite.

```
yum install httpd
chkconfig httpd on
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1 [P,QSA,L]

service httpd start
```

You're done.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use authbind.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind):

> The authbind software allows a program that would normally require superuser privileges to access privileged network services to run as a non-privileged user.

Answer (score 6):

You can change AUTHBIND property of "/etc/default/tomcat6" to "yes" as follows

```
AUTHBIND=yes
```

Restart your tomcat and that will enable you to use available privileged port (1-1023).

Answer (score 1):

i use nginx 2 bind 80 to 8080 which is the port that tomcat bind to.

my nginx configure is like this:

{ server

```
listen 80;
   #which you can edit in /etc/hosts file.It can bind mydomain.com to 127.0.0.1
server_name mydomain.com; 
location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
access_log logs/xxx456.tk_access.log;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced an issue in Linux Mint. When I want to start Tomcat port 80. Permission denied error.

I fixed it with run the tomcat with root permission.

Example:- sudo ./startup.sh

Answer (score -1):

go to address: /tomcat7/server.xml, edit file: use attribute porxyPort="80"

`<Connector port="8080" ...
            proxyPort="80"/>`

which will cause servlets inside this web application to think that all proxied requests were directed to www.mycompany.com on port 80.

Comment: on centos this does not work as ports below 1024 are reserved. the best is to run on port 8080 and change iptables to route requests from 80 to be forwarded to 8080